# Prompt Facebook login dialog for specific user

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

FB.login firstly check logged user in browser session by identifying logged user by cookie. Then it provides authResponse that includes userId,accessToken...etc. But i want to tell Facebook library to use existence user token and prompt some permissions to that user who is belong to that access token.

It is possible use FB.api to make user specific request by specifying access token explicitly. But FB.login does not take existence access token as parameter in documentation.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood - do you want all users to use the same access token on your application, or do you want to perform some specific action for one user who's access token you already know?

Comment: No i don't mean to use same access token for every user. As you mentioned i want to promp login dialog for asking extra permission like user_actions by using access token that is already belong to him and saved in my application.